# Laravel Websockets - Private Channel

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

I am fiddling with Laravel websockets for the first time.
Currently i am just using plain JS WebSocket client (not Laravel Echo).

They way i see it, laravel echo provides an 'authEndpoint' for private and presence channels.

This allows you to create Broadcast::channel() callback that looks like this

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

What puzzles me now, is that when i make a websocket connection with the WebSocket native client and i dont provide the auth endpoint, i can just subscribe to my private channel, and thus bypass all auth completely?

Is this correct or am i missing something?

My goal is to have private channels that reject access is the auth endpoint was not provided.

Comment: Since I cannot comment yet - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341820/laravel-echo-allow-guests-to-connect-to-presence-channel?rq=1

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have checked that link, but that seems to state the opposite from what i am seeing?

Answer (score 0):

What does your broadcast routing look like? Any middleware?

From [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#authorizing-channels):

```
Broadcast::channel('channel', function () {
    // ...
}, ['guards' => ['web', 'admin']]);
```

Comment: I have not applied any middlewares myself currently